# Utilizar query dentro do value de outra query

Tags: sql

É possível - com alguma adaptação de sintaxe - cumprir com o objetivo da seguinte query?

```
insert into X (a, b) values(16, select c from Y where d = e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar das aspas para tal necessidade, criando assim uma `Subquery`.

Uma `Subquery` é basicamente uma query dentro de outra. Ao trabalharmos com subquerys, devemos ficar atentos a certos pontos, como o caso de que uma subquery pode retornar mais de um valor, fazendo com que a sua consulta sql gere um erro (a minha experiência se baseia apenas em bancos de dados `mssql` e `oracle`, sendo assim não sei qual o comportamento dos outros bancos de dados).

Exemplo:

```
insert into X (a, b) values(16, (select c from Y where d = e))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into X (a, b) 
select 16, c from Y where d = e
```

Você pode fazer assim também, sem a palavra **values**.

Answer (score 1):

Voce nem precisa colocar a palavra Values, basta que os valores fiquem dentro do select. Assim:

```
insert into X (a, b) (select "16", c from Y where d = e)
```